# Sigma Algebra generated by null-sets.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I have a particular problem over which I'm sorting of scratching my head. Need a little pointer to start. Let $(\Sigma, X, \mu)$ be a measure space. Find the $\sigma$-algebra generated by all null sets $E \subset X$. Where to begin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Besides null sets, you have complements of null sets.  Anything else?

Comment: Is it just that? I mean null sets and their complements and countable union of null sets which are again null sets?

Comment: Does the case $\mu(X)= \infty$ need special consideration?

Comment: If $\mu(X)$ is finite, a set of measure $\mu(X)$ is the complement of a null set.  This is not necessarily the case if $\mu(X) = \infty$.

Comment: So could you kindly tell me how to handle the case with $\mu(X)=\infty$? In this case, we should say that sets whose compliments have an infinite measure?

Comment: You just consider sets which either have measure $0$ or their complements have measure $0$.  Show these form a $\sigma$-algebra.